# Finite correction factor, strange version?

Tags: statistics

My textbook says the following:

$$\frac {N-n}{N-1}\cdot\frac{\sigma^2}n \approx \left(1-\frac nN\right)\cdot\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

How and Why? This makes no sense whatsoever ^^

Can I prove this somehow (and in a reasonable amount of time)?

Comment: Please give the context and not let us guess what you are asking exactly. I see in my crystal ball that $N$ is large and $n$ is small compared with it. And then we can.. maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is approximately true if we take the case that $N \gg 1$, because we then have:

$$\frac{N-n}{N-1} = \frac{N}{N-1} - \frac{n}{N-1} \approx \frac{N}{N} - \frac{n}{N} = 1-\frac{n}{N}$$

As required in your statement.

Comment: Actually, $n\gg1$ is not required.

Comment: @5xum Yeah, I just realised that! Thanks!

Comment: Always unhelpful to tell a person asking a question that it is  "trivial."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't mean it in a derogatory way, I meant it in an attempt to convey the fact that there's no particular trickery going on, however, I shall take it out if you feel it is/could be interpreted as offensive. Apologies for any offense caused.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{N-n}{N-1} = \frac{N}{N-1}\frac{N-n}{N} = \frac{N}{N-1}\left(\frac{N}{N} - \frac nN\right)$$

For large $N$, you know that $\frac N{N-1}\approx 1$.